# Problem when splitting a F# file into several files

Tags: .net, f#

I am trying to separate a F# file in multiple files, although I am currently stuck. I have tried passing the following lines from my original `Main.fs` to an `Ast.fs`. In `Ast.fs` I've put:

```
...
type StartPosition = Position
type EndPosition = Position
type TokenPosition = TokenPosition of StartPosition * EndPosition
...
```

I've then added an

```
open Ast
```

to my `Main.fs`. When trying to build, I am now getting the following error

```
This expression was expected to have type     StartPosition    but here has type     Position
```

over `sp` and `ep`:

```
let parse_token token = pipe3 getPosition token getPosition (fun sp t ep -> (t, TokenPosition(sp, ep)))
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense, I guess, as `StartPosition` and `EndPosition` are no more than "typedefs" of Position. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be getting this error message if `StartPosition` was just an alias of `Position`, so there must be something else that went wrong. It is hard to tell without more complete sample, but here are a few things to check:

- Are you referring to the right `Position` type? (You can check full information about the type by looking at the tool tip that you get when you place mouse pointer over the type name)
- Is the `Position` type defined in just a single file? (If another file re-defined it, then you'd have two different types named `Position`)

Comment: Spot on! Had forgot to "open FParsec" in my AST.fs.